# Serialization of google storage response object to json

Tags: serialization, google-cloud-storage, deserialization, json-deserialization, json-serialization

```
import com.google.api.gax.paging.Page;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;

public class ListBuckets {
  public static void listBuckets(String projectId) {
    // The ID of your GCP project
    // String projectId = "your-project-id";

    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
    Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.toJson(buckets);
    
  }
}
```

How to serialize the buckets response object to json?
buckets reponse will be dynamic based upon the BucketListOption provided as input parameter in list() method. I don't want to call all individual method to retrieve the values like bucket.getName() .

gson.toJson(buckets); // what I am doing wrong, Can anyone point the issue?